# Delphi: how to automatically create property from private field?

Tags: class, delphi, automation, code-completion

I already know how to use inline templates (prop/propf + CTRL-J) to declare properties that automatically create their private field and their getters/setters, but how do I do the opposite?

I have 166 private fields already declared. Is there a way to have the Delphi IDE automatically create properties for each one of them?

This is what I have:

```
TMyObject = class(TPersistent)
private
  FFirstProp: boolean;
  FSecondProp: boolean;
  // 164 more of them...
```

This is what I would like to (ideally) have the IDE create for me:

```
published
  property FirstProp: boolean read FFirstProp write FFirstProp;
  property SecondProp: boolean read FSecondProp write FSecondProp;
  // and the other 164...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not an option. Your best bet is to do it the other way around. Convert all these to property definitions and then produce the private fields. Because how is the IDE supposed to know if you want either getters or setters? Or if you want to link them directly or indirectly? Or what the defaults should be?

Comment: Or which of those private fields you want to be properties and which you do not? Or whether you want them to be public or published?

Comment: Can use propf again, type FirstProp and no additional field will be declared.

Comment: Jerry, a simple code generator that "assumes" direct read/write of the private field would be enough for me. After all, even the other way around the IDE must make assumptions...

Comment: Thank you Sertac, I know that... I was trying to avoid so much typing...

Comment: Personally I don't know such feature in the Delphi IDE. But you always  can to use the third-party text editor with macros support. Notepad++ is the good example.

Comment: You could use an external script to generate this. Would be simple enough in, say, Python.

Comment: David, thank you, I am actually doing it with a tiny script. Also, this question is not a duplicate. I actually saw the other answer and even quoted part of it in my question (Ctrl-J) so no duplicate here, thank you.

Comment: you could create an app that hat pares the code and generates you what you want , that way you could have it do the getters and setters for you if required, for example  and have tags after the declaration that tell your app what to do, it could also write the stuff getter and setter functions/procedures

TMyObject = class(TPersistent)
private
  FFirstProp: boolean; //Get,Set
  FSecondProp: boolean; //Set

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me. Both questions ask how to auto create props efficiently.

Comment: I had read that question and answer before asking mine. If that was the answer I was looking for, do you think I would ask this question? This is the other way around PrivateSymbol -> Property, not Property -> PrivateSymbol. "How to auto create props efficiently" is too simplistic. Then why don't we flag as duplicate all questions about properties cause they're all "about properties"? Sorry, it's really not the same...

Comment: *If that was the answer I was looking for, do you think I would ask this question?* It's not about answers. It's about questions. And sure it's the other way around in your head. But all you really want to do is make properties effectively. Which is what the other question asks. Doesn't actually matter which way round.

Comment: @David "Would be simple enough in, say, Python. " Or you could just take a page from Python's playbook and simply make everything public and program for consenting adults. :-) Seriously it's just madness to declare everything twice like that without needing real getters and setters. If you have to consider using another language to generate code for your language, that's got to be a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @alcalde I agree that if the class really contains 164 properties of that form, then they should just be published data members.

Comment: @David: the way around matters, and the proof is that - in fact - there is a way to do it one way (prop + Ctrl-J), and there's no way to do it the other way around.

Comment: So if I reopen the question and somebody answers, "What you ask for cannot be done", then you'll upvote and accept?

Comment: Yes, cause that someone would have answered my question and deserves the acceptance and the upvote.